# Oracle: how to select rows that are not duplicated

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to eliminate the ones with an X in value and repeated.  If they don't have an X, they stay, if they have an X but are not repeated they stay.  Can you please help?

Table

```
Id        Value          

1.          A.               
2.          X.               
3.          X.               
3.          C.              
3.          D.                
4.          X.    
4.          F
5.          G
6.          Z
7.          X
8.          X
8.          G
```

Result from query should be:

```
1. A
2. X
5. G
6. Z
7. X
```

Comment: use `distinct` keyword in select query if you want to see unique `Value` column values

Comment: I am unable to understand your question, can you explain it better? Thanks

Comment: SELECT id FROM Table1
GROUP BY Id
having COUNT(Id) =1

Comment: What happens if they are duplicate, but neither of them has an X?, for instance 9A, 9C, but not 9X. Do you return 9A and 9C, or only one of them? If so, which?

Comment: What happens if they are duplicate, all of them having an X?

Comment: Sylvain: They can't have the same id and an X.

Comment: GolezTrol.  There are two selecting criteria.  First, i have to check if the row has an X. If it does, then i have to see if the id of that row is repeated, if it is, it will be discarded from the query results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that helps:

```
SELECT Id,
       Value
  FROM(SELECT Id,
              Value,
              COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) cnt,
              SUM(DECODE(Value, 'X', 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) sumx
         FROM your_table
      )
 WHERE cnt = 1 OR sumx = 0;
```

Comment: I worked perfectly, thank you sooo very much.. This community rules..!! I appreciate it guys and look forward to contribute and pay it forward.. have a great day everyone..!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that sufficient?

```
SELECT "Id", MIN("Value") "Value" FROM T
GROUP BY "Id" HAVING COUNT("Id") = 1
ORDER BY "Id"
```

It will discard multiple only-non-X values for a given id too. At the very least, according to your sample data, it *seems* to produce the desired result:

```
ID  VALUE
1   A
2   X
5   G
6   Z
7   X
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81baa/10

Comment: (Repeated comment, because the feeling is the same.. thank you) I worked perfectly, thank you sooo very much.. This community rules..!! I appreciate it guys and look forward to contribute and pay it forward.. have a great day everyone..!! :)